# Rancher 2.1 and Vmware Storage Class

Tags: vmware, rancher, node-vsphere

i have a vpshere lab environment. I used rancher 2.1 to deploy a kubernetes cluster with vsphere node template . now i wold like to use the vmware storage class. unfortunately my configuration doesn't work. do someone have 
experience with rancher 2.0 ad vmware storage class?

[image]

Comment: have you seen these?

https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes/documentation/existing.html

https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes/documentation/guestbook.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to use vsphere storage with a kubernetes cluster, you will need to have the vsphere cloud provider enabled.

Some information on how to do so can be found here: https://rancher.com/docs/rke/v0.1.x/en/config-options/cloud-providers/vsphere/